# Display different permutations of combn() in a graph or text output

Tags: r

Say I have the following list:

```
colors <- c("red", "green", "purple", "yellow")
```

I would like to find all of the combinations of these colors, but only using each of the color once. I can combine the colors, but eventually I must get to only a single 4 color combination (I'm not sure what this is called, would be grateful for some terminology help here as well):

```
col1 <- combn(colors, 1, simplify=FALSE)
col2 <- combn(colors, 2, simplify=FALSE)
col3 <- combn(colors, 3, simplify=FALSE)
col4 <- combn(colors, 4, simplify=FALSE)
```

I have calculated the total number of different combinations (regardless of error) using the following:

```
total_color_combo <- length(col1) + length(col2) + length(col3 ) + length(col4)
```

`total_color_combo` results in 15. This number is the total possible combinations I can have regardless of order.

**Q: How can I display the permutations in a readable output, preferably graphically?**

Ideally I could have R output a graph that looks like the following:

```
     Red    Green    Purple
    /   \   /   \        \
  Green  Purple Yellow   Yellow
    /  \       \            \
 Purple Yellow Yellow       Green
   /
 Yellow
```

Using this output, I get to the first combination of all the different variables quickly. Preferably, I would like to output this as a graph, but I haven't figured out how to even save it as a table properly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also, my real data is significantly larger than this.

Comment: What is the approach you want to use to build this graph? Could you explain an approach to organize nodes and edges in the graph from col1, col2, col3, and col4?

Comment: You seem to have `Green,Purple,Yellow` and `Purple,Yellow,Green`

Comment: @Henry. Good catch, in the second "iteration" of col2, red actually has three things attached to it, `green`, `purple`, and `yellow`. There is no `purple`, `yellow`, `green`. I'll try to figure out how to fix this formatting error.

Comment: @josilber I'm stuck at trying to figure out how to compile the `combn()` results into a something readable by a graphics package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To output the file in a readable format I settled with a text output. I used the following code to create a matrix of each of the combinations and from the `plyr` package, I used `rbind.fill.matrix` to create a single matrix, which I then wrote to a file. Here is the code that I used.

```
col1 <- matrix(unlist(combn(colors, 1, simplify=FALSE)), ncol=1, byrow=TRUE)
col2 <- matrix(unlist(combn(colors, 2, simplify=FALSE)), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
col3 <- matrix(unlist(combn(colors, 3, simplify=FALSE)), ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)
col4 <- matrix(unlist(combn(colors, 4, simplify=FALSE)), ncol=4, byrow=TRUE)
```

I then merged the files into a combined matrix.

```
cColors <- rbind.fill.matrix(col1, col2, col3, col4)
```

I then removed the NAs so that it was more easily readable.

```
cColors[is.na(cColors)] <- ""
```

I then wrote the table to a text file using `write.table`.

This was a simple solution that worked for the absolute bare minimum. I would still like to figure out how to graph it.